# What is the maximum Chromecast message throughput?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

A sender app can send [messages](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#messages) to change the state of the receiver app. Is there a cap to message throughput (other than network constraints)? Would it be feasible to send a live media stream using messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the data message channel is not built for that and is not going to do a good job if you try to use it for such purposes. The data channel is really a control channel, sending small messages infrequently to control the behavior, etc (it has a cap size of 64k if I recall correctly). Use other means (say a web server) if you need to stream media.